# Powershell alias doesn't seem to work with alias name that contains -

Tags: powershell

When I type :

```
Set-Alias -Name test2 -Value test
```

Get-Alias shows test2 points to test

But with

```
Set-Alias -Name test2-clone -Value test
```

Get-Alias shows test2-clone but it doesn't point to test

Comment: So, what does it do? Anything? I don't see why that wouldn't work. Is `test` a function? What PowerShell version are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the alias does not display properly, it does still get set correctly:

```sh
# Set two examples
Set-Alias TestAlias -Value Get-Date
Set-Alias Test-Hyphen -Value Get-Date

# Doesn't display correctly from Get-Alias
Get-Alias Test*

CommandType Name                   Version Source
----------- ----                   ------- ------
Alias       TestAlias -> Get-Date                ## Works
Alias       Test-Hyphen                          ## Doesn't show command?

# Check the alias properties to see the command definition is set correctly:
Get-Alias Test-Hyphen | Select DisplayName,Definition

DisplayName Definition
----------- ----------
Test-Hyphen Get-Date  

# Use the alias, and it works fine:
Test-Hyphen

Wednesday, April 27, 2022 10:00:08 AM
```

<s>This is an (old) bug in the View for commandinfo type objects defined in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShellCore.format.ps1xml`</s>

This is on purpose, per the `Get-Alias` [help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-alias?view=powershell-7.2):

> The output shows the  ->  format that was introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0. This format is used only for aliases that do not include hyphens, because aliases with hyphens are typically preferred names for cmdlets and functions, rather than nicknames.

Comment: Nice sleuthing. Since the bug still is still present in the current PowerShell Core version, I encourage you to file a bug at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues